# Php - Calculating number based on percentage, how to drop all precision after 2 dec places?

Tags: php

I am having a problem calculating prices from within a php script.

After much debate, I have realised that the cause of my woes belongs to the way php actually works. As this is more than likely known by most, i'll thought i should point this out and save time for people that have not already realised this.

Php will produce a finite result during the multiplication process. As in, 1.246256343. Now i have noticed that the point of sale system (non php based) used by out store seems to drop any digit after two decimal places, regardless of its' rounding potential. As in 1.246 is calculated as 1.24 and not 1.25 as one might naturally think.

Now with this said, I am looking for a way to produce this effect when using php to do this calculation. I have been dabbling with `round()` for quite some time now, but fear that this is the root of the problem in the first place, as it will round 1.246 to 1.25 if used in this instance:

```
$prCalcPrice = round($prPrice / 1.02, 2);
```

Or this one

```
$prCalcPrice = round($prPrice / 1.02, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

Now I need a way to output the result excluding any digit value after two decimal places, so essentially a result of 1.246 will produce a value of 1.24, and not 1.25.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions regarding this?

Also, if this has been a problem for you in the past, and you have found any useful info in the form of tutorials or other pages, please post them!

Comment: Are you telling me 1.41999 is closer to 1.41 than 1.42? That's very unscientific.

Comment: @NullUserException It is very, but this legacy system works that way. As we are planning on offering an online catalouge, the simplest approach so far has been to work with it... Up until now :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested in 2 decimal places, there are more than one way to do it.

```
$n = 21.2463;

// select 2 digit characters after a point
preg_match('/(.*\.[0-9]{2})/', $n, $matches);

echo $matches[1];   // 21.24

// multiply by 100, cast to int, divide by 100
echo ((int)($n*100)/100); // 21.24
```

etc.

Comment: The latter eventually proved most useful to me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`floor`](http://php.net/floor) function combined with a multiplation and division by 10^2 (as you want to round with a precision of two decimal digits):

```
$roundedPrice = floor($price * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this for display purposes only, and don't need to actually store the number as you describe, the proper method is sprintf:

```
sprintf( '%.2f', $number )
```

Regex is unnecessarily expensive, and doing extra math to format it is just messy.

This may not be in your control now, but If you need to actually capture the value for further calculation, your best bet is to not work with floating points to begin with.  In fact, any time you're working with financial system, you should not be using floating point numbers.  Floating point calculations cannot be guaranteed to be accurate.  Transform your money values into integers before doing math on them.

```
1.29 dollars = 129 cents 
129 cents * .50 = 64.5 cents 
intval(64.5) = $0.64
```

To account for the remainder, usually systems store values as Nths of cents.

Comment: My apologies, after testing this out, it won't work for you.  I didn't realize sprintf() will actually do rounding on the formatted number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, but its not for display purposes. The system actually calculates the total cost on this rounded figure, excluding after decimal values after 2. What a headache!