# PHP Array, access array value by a range of indexes

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, range, arrayaccess

My case is i have price of an item in a range of Kilogram, like

```
price in range 0.01-0.04 is 5
price in range 0.05-0.09 is 30
price in range 0.1-0.15 is 50
```

Here is sample of array like i want

```
$prices = array("0.01-0.04"=>5,"0.05-0.09"=>30);
```

now i want to make an array so when user input `0.02 it should return price in range 0.01-0.04` which is 5, similarly if user `input 0.07 so it should return 30`.

**how to make an array in PHP to access array via a range of indexes?**

Comment: you have to go with if statements

Comment: i know but they are alot of condition, i want it via indexing for faster search...

Comment: this is a range condition, I don't know if you can implement this with arrays

Comment: how about rounding the number down but with a percentage?

Answer (score 2):

**Try This code**

```
 <?php
        $price = array(
            array(
                'min_range' => 0.1,
                'max_range' => 0.4,
                'price'     => 5
            ),
            array(
                'min_range' => 0.5,
                'max_range' => 0.9,
                'price'     => 30
            ),
            array(
                'min_range' => 1.0,
                'max_range' => 1.5,
                'price'     => 50
            ),
        );

        $input = 0.7;

        foreach( $price as $p){
            if($input>=$p['min_range'] && $input<=$p['max_range']){
                echo $p['price'];
                break;
            }
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: that's good but will take much of time, there is no use of array then.

Answer (score 2):

set $no variable as number for which you are finding the range

```
    <?php

$no = 0.05;
$ranges = array
  (
  array(0.01,0.04,5),
  array(0.05,0.09,30),
  array(0.1,0.15,50)
  );
  $foundFlag=false;
 foreach ($ranges as $range) { 

        if($no>=$range[0] && $no<=$range[1])
        {
        $foundFlag=true;
            echo "$range[2]";
        }
} 
  if($foundFlag==false)
  {
    echo "range not found";
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in that way as well,

```
  <?php

     $input = $_POST['userInput'];
     $count = 0;

     $arr =Array();
     $arr[0]=0.01;
     $arr[1]=0.04;
     $arr[2]=0.05;
     $arr[3]=0.09;
     $arr[4]=0.1;
     $arr[5]=0.15;

     $price =Array();
     $price[0] =5;
     $price[2] =30;
     $price[4] =50;

     while(count($arr)>$count)
        if($arr[$count] != null && $arr[$count+1] != null)
        {
             if($input >$arr[$count] && $input <$arr[$count+1])
             {
                echo "price is $price[$count]";
             }
        }
        $count = $count +2;
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something that looks it could be used for your condition

[Php - Calculating number based on percentage, how to drop all precision after 2 dec places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826910/php-calculating-number-based-on-percentage-how-to-drop-all-precision-after-2)